# ScrollView with too many Textviews (over 400)

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, horizontalscrollview, drawtext

I was able to make an app with a scrollable calendar, like the image:

[Preview and Component Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3MEn.png)

The calendar itself, for 2016, looks like this:

[2016 Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kw8p.png)

It's a five week based calendar, and it's meant to be built like that, for its purposes.
When you run the app you have a calendar, with a week or so displayed.Then you can scroll the days and see the whole calendar. The months names stand still on the left.
Clicking the arrows updates the calendar, showing past and future years, as expected.

It works.

I still don't understand A LOT of java, but I could manage to make it work.
One search here, another there, one tutorial here, another example of code there...

It works.

The problem is: it's too slow to update the calendar.
It takes about 3 seconds or so to update the days, and you can't scroll the calendar during that time.
After the update the scroll is normal. You go right and left. No problem.
It's the processes to update all those TextViews that's killing me... Yes, I do have A LOT of TextViews, and that's where I think I could start getting some help.

The calendar is designed to display five weeks, monday to sunday, which gives me 35 TextViews per month... that's 420 TextViews...
The following method clears the calendar prior to update:

```
public void Clears_the_Calendar() {
    int iId;
    TextView tvDay;

    for (iId = 0; iId < 420; iId++) {
        tvDay= (TextView)findViewById(iarrTextView_Days_ids[iId]);
        tvDay.setText(" ");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use the array iarrTextView_Days_ids to reference the TextViews. It looks like:

```
int[] iarrTextView_Days_ids = new int[]
                           {R.id.M01_D01, R.id.M01_D02, ... , R.id.M01_D34, R.id.M01_D35,
                            R.id.M02_D01, R.id.M02_D02, ... , R.id.M02_D34, R.id.M02_D35,
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            R.id.M12_D01, R.id.M12_D02, ... , R.id.M12_D34, R.id.M12_D35}
```

And this is what I use to build the calendar:

```
private void mtBuild_Calendar(int iYear, int iColumn) {
    int i, iId, iDay, iMonth1, iMonth2, iTotal_Days;
    TextView tvDay;

    Date dtDate = null;
    int iRight_Column = 35;
    String sDay, sDate = "01/01/" + iYear;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Calendar cMain_Calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cAuxiliary_Calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
        dtDate = sdf.parse(sDate);
        cMain_Calendar.setTime(dtDate);
        cAuxiliary_Calendar.setTime(dtDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    cMain_Calendar.setTime(dtDate);
    cAuxiliary_Calendar.setTime(dtDate);

    Clears_the_Calendar();

    // displays "1" (jan/1), according to iColumn, which is determined in another method:
    iId = iColumn - 1;
    tvDay = (TextView)findViewById(iarrTextView_Days_ids[iId]);
    tvDay.setText("1");

    // It's not important to be extremely precise about leap years:
    if ((iYear % 4) == 0) {
        iTotal_Days = 366;
    } else {
        iTotal_Days = 365
    }

    for (i = 1; i < iTotal_Days - 1; i++) {
        // Adds a day to the cAuxiliary_Calendar and compares its MONTH with the previous day from cMain_Calendar
        cAuxiliary_Calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        iMonth1 = cMain_Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        iMonth2 = cAuxiliary_Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        // Performs the comparisons needed to change the months:
        if (iColumn < iRight_Column) {
            if (iMonth2 == iMonth1) {
                iColumn = iColumn + 1;
                iId = iId + 1;
            } else {
                iColumn = iColumn + 1;
                iId = iId + 36;
            }
        } else {
            if (iMonth2 == iMonth1) {
                iColumn = 1;
                iId = iId - 34;
            } else {
                iColumn = 1;
                iId = iId + 1;
            }
        }
        // Adds a day to cMain_Calendar and displays it in the proper place according to iId:
        cMain_Calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        iDay = cMain_Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        sDay = Integer.toString(iDay);
        tvDay = (TextView) findViewById(iarrTextView_Days_ids[iId]);
        tvDay.setText(sDay);
    }
}
```

At first a method clears all the 420 TextViews, and then just the 365 or 366 needed for the year are fulfilled.
Still, that's a lot of work... this afternoon I started taking a look at canvas.drawText
For a moment it seemed to me that it would be faster, cause for what I understood TextView uses canvas inside its core. But I couldn't even find a way to make a simple canvas.drawText to work inside the ScrollView.
So the questions are:

Should I use canvas.drawText instead of TextViews? How can I do that?
Or, is there any other faster way to display 365 numbers like the app is supposed to do?

(new info, not sure how it looks...)
Trying new thigs:
Perhaps I misunderstood what adapters can do, but for what I've learned it won't help me... cause once an year is fully loaded into the view there's no delay in scrolling the calendar. The problem is how long it takes to refresh all the 365 TextViews when I want to change from one year to another. In fact, I could manage to reduce that delay to less than 1 second at this point, cause I finally follow the Android Studio advice about too many nested weights.. All my TextViews where using that attibute on its style. I removed them all, letting weights just for the LinearLayouts.

Right now I'm stuck in trying to find a way to pass a string to a method which could draw a text into the view. I still can't get a drawText to work inside the ScrollView, cause I can't find a way to call it. Seems to me that it would only works inside an onDraw, which only triggers when I load a view. But I need to get drawText doing its job 420 times (when I clear the calendar) plus 365 times when a new calendar is shown.
Am I supposed to load 800 views into the ScrollView, each time I want to chage the year ???

I also changed the main LinearLayout to RelativeLAyout, but things are getting weird cause I had to set a lot of heights (which was 0dp prior to the change) and now I'm having troubles on changing from portrait to landscape... but that's a minor issue.

Comment: Wow. I'm really impressed that you managed to get *this* to work. Yes. 400 TextViews is definitively too much. You should have a look at what adapters are and how they work, since you should not have views that are not visible. Especially not 300 of them. There are multiple questions here concerning calendar views, and most if not all of them are too broad, since there is no easy way to accomplish this (properly). And yes, you can draw your own stuff on the canvas, which for sure is faster, but this also is complicated and "onClick" will not work, unless you implement it yourself

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @DavidMedenjak  I read somewhere about adapter, but didn't take much time over that. I will take a look again. Could you suggest some place I can get nice tutorials? http://developer.android.com just kills me...

Comment: Well. You will have to come up with your own kind of adapter. Or your own custom view. Or a mix of both. And no, sadly, I don't know of any tutorials covering those topics in a way that would help you. Starting with the official documentation is although a safe bet. You will need it sooner or later.